# Does changing the src of an image with a width and height cause DOM thrashing?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser

If I have an image tag with a width/height set `<img width=x height=x src=blank_pixel />` and I change the src to some image url will this cause the dom layout to be invalidated?

Comment: Not really, did you try it?

Comment: looks like its a yes

Answer (score -1):

Using chrome dev tools I see next sequence:

1. Recalculate style + Layout + Update layer tree
2. Paint
3. Composite Layers

My answer is yes. Browser donwload new image, scale it (if it's necessary) and then calculate layout, do the paint and composite the image.